# What is $\int \frac1{1+(a\tan x)^2}dx$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

What is $\int \frac1{1+(a\tan x)^2} \mathrm dx$?

This is a difficult integral. If you can, please give a step-by-step solution - I would be delighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that hard if you take the suggestion from Clayton:

$u=a \tan{x}$; $x = \arctan{(u/a)}$; $dx=a\, du/(u^2+a^2)$.  Then the integral is

$$a \int \frac{du}{(u^2+a^2)(u^2+1)} $$

Assume $a \ne 1$.  Use partial fractions:

$$\frac{1}{u^2+a^2}-\frac{1}{u^2+1} = \frac{1-a^2}{(u^2+a^2)(u^2+1)}$$

so the integral becomes

$$\frac{a}{1-a^2} \int du \left (\frac{1}{u^2+a^2}-\frac{1}{u^2+1} \right ) = \frac{a}{1-a^2} \left (\frac{1}{a} \arctan{\frac{u}{a}} - \arctan{u} \right )+C$$

Therefore

$$\int \frac{dx}{1+a^2 \tan^2{x}} = \frac{1}{1-a^2} \left (x - a \arctan{(a \tan{x})}\right )+C $$

When $a=1$, however, we get that the integral is

$$\int \frac{dx}{1+\tan^2{x}} = \int dx \cos^2{x} = \frac{x}{2} + \frac12 \sin{x} \cos{x} + C$$

Comment: Unless $a^2=1$, in which case...?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: thanks, and stay tuned.

Comment: Clever use of partial fractions - I spent a lot of time on algebra. You guys are better than wolfram alpha :). BTW is there a way to keep the constant in the result (even if it is equal to 1)?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use a substitution $u=a\tan(x)$, and note that $\tan(x)=\frac{u}{a}$.

Comment: And then partial fractions? I tried that, but with u = tanx substitution. The final result was the same integral, but multiplied by a^2. Is that the correct result?

Comment: Yes; after the substitution, you end up with an integral which can be solved using partial fractions.

Comment: @user103199: I can confirm that setting $u=\tan x$ is no worse than the hint provided here. If you get the same integral multiplied by $a^2$ though, that cannot be right.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Just to be clear, my "Yes" was only to the first question :)